# Talend - split a string to n rows

Tags: talend

I would like to split a string in a column to n rows in Talend.

For example :

| column |
| --- |
| 2aabbccdd |

The first number is the "n" which I use to define the row lenght, so the expected result should be :

row 1 = aa

row 2 = bb

row 3 = cc

row 4 = dd

The idea here is to iterate on the string and cut it every 2 characters.

Any idea please ?

Comment: The number is always 1 digit or can be more than that?

Comment: It can be more than 1 digit, its on 4 digits 0002 ( for my case its 0002 = 2)

Comment: Ok, so it's always 4 digits then :) we need to know so that we can parse it

Comment: Yes its always 4 digits !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a tJavaFlex to split the string, with a trick to have n rows coming out of it.
[image]

tJavaFlex's main code:

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(row1.str.substring(0, 4)); //get n from the first 4 characters
String str2 = row1.str.substring(4); //get the string after n

int nbParts = (str2.length() + 1) / n;

System.out.println("number of parts = " + nbParts);

for (int i = 0; i < nbParts; i++)
{
    String part = str2.substring(i * n);
    if(part.length() > n)
    {
        part = part.substring(0, n);
    }

    row2.str = part;
```

And tJavaFlex's end code is just a closing brace:

```
}
```

The trick is to use a for loop in the main code, but only close it in the end code.
tFixedFlowInput contains just one column holding the input string.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! Actually I don't have the same result :

https://imgur.com/2NpwExE

Comment: Can you show your input string and the java code you have?

Comment: Yes sure : https://imgur.com/3xHJl6Z    https://imgur.com/a/a2TsfFe

Comment: It seems that the code is producing the expected number of rows but somehow they don't end up in the output row. Since I don't see the beginning of your main java code; can you try diabling the propagate data option of tJavaFlex ? (Auto propagation des données)

Comment: Here is the main code :

// here is the main part of the component,
// a piece of code executed in the row
// loop
int n = Integer.parseInt(row9.message.substring(0, 4)); //get n from the first 4 characters
String str2 = row9.message.substring(4); //get the string after n

int nbParts = (str2.length() + 1) / n;

System.out.println("number of parts = " + nbParts);

for (int i = 0; i < nbParts; i++)
{
    String part = str2.substring(i * n);
    if(part.length() > n)
    {
        part = part.substring(0, n); 
    }

    row9.message = part;

Comment: When I disable the (Auto propagation des données) the result returns nulls :

https://imgur.com/lfBiITK

Comment: Your code looks exactly like mine, I don't understand why it doesn't work.. Here's my test job which works: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/72eb34bc465cdb2197969ecddfe8385b20220313105051/8a0d1a Can you try it ?

Comment: I just found the problem ! In the java code I was using my first input row and not the tjavaflex output for the row.message = part ! Its working now

Comment: Cool glad you got it working :)